# Please help in translating this Chinese text

Tags: cjk

Someone help in translating the following text from image, it's Chinese.
[alt text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihbuD.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, completely off-topic. Good luck though.

Comment: Chinese OCR http://users.belgacom.net/chardic/cocr2.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sentence might appear a little messy, might need reordering to understand clearly. I'm also not sure what device this is, so the nouns might be incorrect. Nevertheless, here's the translation:

There is a set of administrative code within the electronics locking system. The code can be 4-12 digits (users can define the number of digits according to their memory and security needs). The administrative code possesses the highest privilege. It not only can be used to open the door, but also change another user's code or add remove cards.

Editing the administrative code
Press PIN and you will hear a short beep, then a blue LED will light up, this means it is now in settings mode. Press the key to enter the original administrative code (It is set to 1.2.3.4 originally), then press *, if the code is incorrect, the device will beep three times and exit settings mode, the blue LED will turn off. If the code is correct, the blue LED will flash and there will be a long beep, this means you can now enter new administrative code. Enter the new administrative code, then press *. The blue LED will flash and there will be a short beep. Enter the new administrative code again and press * to confirm. If the codes match, the blue LED will flash twice and there will be a long beep and it will exit settings mode, the blue LED will turn off. If the codes don't match, there will be 3 short beeps and you have to enter the new administrative code again. During the operation, the duration between entering 2 digits cannot be longer than 20 seconds, if it exceeds, please press * or # to exit settings mode.

[Example: entering 121868 as the new administrative code]

Editing user's code
Press PIN and you will hear a short beep, then a blue LED will light up, this means it is now in settings mode. Press the key to enter the administrative code (your new administrative code), then press #. If the code is incorrect, the device will beep three times and exit settings mode, the blue LED will turn off. If the code is correct, the blue LED will flash and there will be a long beep, and you can now enter the new code. Enter your new code and press #, the blue LED will flash and there will be a short beep, enter the new code again and press #, if the codes match, the blue LED will flash twice and there will be a long beep and it will exit settings mode. If the codes don't match, there will be 3 short beeps and you have to enter the new administrative code again. During the operation, the duration between entering 2 digits cannot be longer than 20 seconds, if it exceeds, please press * or # to exit settings mode.